# Insert complete lines with Emacs + Evil

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

In Vim, I often move lines by deleting them (either with `dd` or visual line mode), moving my cursor to the new position, then `p` to put them in:

```
first
second
third
```

And if my cursor is on the line *second*, I can use `ddp` to move it down:

```
first
third
second
```

But with Emacs + Evil mode, putting the line back doesn't work as expected: if, for example, my cursor is on the *i* in *third* when I hit `p`, I end up with:

```
first
thisecondrd
```

How can I make Emacs + Evil mode insert new lines when putting entire yanked lines?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with evil version 1.0-dev. I recognize that case when I only delete a word, not a line. Think about using move-text when you can.

Comment: I also can't reproduce the problem (same evil version).

Comment: I add the same kind of problem and I was because of a custom copy-paste function in my emacs init file.

Answer (score 1):

I use C-a to go to the beginning of the line (^ in evil-mode, probably) before yanking, if I want that behaviour. If you do this often, you can probably come up with your own thing for yank, although you have to figure out during the kill part if you're doing that. (Or you can check if the yanked thing has newlines, I guess?)

There's a transpose-lines command, by the way (C-x C-t in regular Emacs binding - someone suggested binding this to xtl - https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/my-keybindings.el).

Comment: It seems like the problem is that I also need to be at the beginning of the line I'm inserting into… is there an "insert on new line"? Or is that a thing I'll need to write?

Answer (score 1):

If I find my cursor on a line that I want to move, my natural response is to first delete the line into the kill ring with either `C-a` `C-k` `C-k` or `C-a` `C-space` `C-n` `C-w` (either of which can also grab several-line sequences by duplicating either the `C-k` or `C-n` or prefixing the `C-n` with a numeric argument) and then travel to the beginning of the line where I want to paste and doing a `C-y` yank.

Note that Emacs considers a file to be a steam of characters, in which newline or carriage return is not special. Unlike in vi, you can `C-f` forward right over a newline exactly as though it is a normal character; backspace over it; or include it in a deleted and yanked buffer. It is exactly like any other character. Perhaps Emacs is for people who think of files as sequences of characters — some of which happen to be newlines — and vi is for people who think of their file as lines, that are magically separated by who-knows-what but it certainly is not like any other character.

Answer (score 0):

If the main use case you are trying to address is *moving lines up or down* (as opposed to the more general question of how to "make Emacs + Evil mode insert new lines when putting entire yanked lines"), I suggest you try out [`move-text`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/move-text.el).

It is a very small add-on package that provides two commands (`move-text-up` and `move-text-down`) for moving lines up and down, respectively. You can be *anywhere* on a line and call these; there is *no need to kill or yank anything*, and they work for regions as well.

For example, calling `move-line-down` in this situation (point right after `second`):

```
first line
second| line
third line
```

will produce

```
first line
third line
second| line
```

As you would expect, moving the current line (or region) up or down `n` lines works by calling the appropriate command with a numeric prefix.

The commands are bound to <kbd>M-up</kbd> and <kbd>M-down</kbd> by default but you should be able to rebind them to key sequences of your liking via

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "mu" 'move-line-up)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "md" 'move-line-down)
```

`move-text` is `package-install`able from MELPA.